# Arduino Mega not receiving data from Neo-6M

Tags: arduino-mega, gps

I am using the trying to get data from the Neo-6M GPS module with an Arduino mega, but, the condition 'While (gpsSerial.available() > 0' is being met. I believe this means the no bytes are being transferred from the module to the serial port but I'm not sure why.
The light on the Neo-6M was blinking which means it getting a lock but not giving out the data.

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

// Choose two Arduino pins to use for software serial
int RXPin = 19;
int TXPin = 18;

//Default baud of NEO-6M is 9600
int GPSBaud = 9600;

// Create a software serial port called "gpsSerial"
SoftwareSerial gpsSerial(RXPin, TXPin);

void setup()
{
  // Start the Arduino hardware serial port at 9600 baud
  Serial.begin(9600);

  // Start the software serial port at the GPS's default baud
  gpsSerial.begin(GPSBaud);
  Serial.write("123");
}

void loop()
{
  // Displays information when new sentence is available.
  while (gpsSerial.available() > 0)
    Serial.write(gpsSerial.read());
}
```

I had it working on an Uno by connecting to pins 2,3 rather then 18 and 19. I have also tried swapping the 18 and 19 pins over but still noting.

Thanks for the help

EDIT:
I have the RX and TX plugged into the mega at pins 1 and 2, however, it will only print GPS information when the reset button is pressed or held down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all pins on the Mega support software serial, have a read below:

https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SoftwareSerial

Pins 18 / 19 are actually hardware serial pins so should not need the use of software serial.

Edit, should have noted to use hardware pins 18 / 19 you would use the constructor Serial1.begin(9600)